# Do Facebook Ads and Google Analytics changed the way they count newly registered users since February 2020?

Tags: google-analytics, users, facebook-ads-manager

I am monitoring the difference of daily new registered users to our service between the three our database and the two other tools we use to make sure everything is allright: Google Analytics seems to overestimate the number of newly registered users and Facebook to underestimate. Yet it seems that since February 17th, 2020 there these discrepences incremented. And it incremented even more in February 2021.

[image]

I haven't found any technical reason about that in the news. My guess would be that there is a time lag?

Comment: Why is your FB line below zero?   How is it possible to have a negative number of new registrations?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @StephenOstermiller they’re both difference with the metabase output. Which is thought to be the most reliable source, so far ...